# X-editable validation rules to check for only numbers OR a certain string

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, x-editable

I'm using Bootstrap x-editable, and was wondering how you can do validation to accept either numbers or a certain value in the field.

For example, I was trying to get this to work:

```
 $('#units-1').editable({
     container: 'body',
     type: 'text',
     pk: 1,
     url: '/post',
     validate: function(value) {
         if($.trim(value) == '') {
             return 'Units is required.';
         }
         else if (($.isNumeric(value) == '') || ($.trim(value) != 'EA')) {
             return 'Only numbers allowed or EA';
    }
   }
 });
```

But, I can either check for only numbers, or the value of "EA", but not both. How do I write the JavaScript so that either a number OR "EA" will pass the validation and save the edit?

Here is another one I tried, but again, I can only get either the "must be a number" or the "must be EA" to work:

```
validate: function(value) {
  var validNumberRegex = /^[0-9]+$/;
  if($.trim(value) == '') {
        return 'Units is required.';
    }
    else if ((!validNumberRegex.test(value)) || ($.trim(value) !== 'EA')) {
    return 'Only numbers or EA allowed';
  }
},
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this validate function should do fine

```
validate: function(value) {
     if($.trim(value) == '') {
         return 'Units is required.';
     }
     if (($.isNumeric(value) == '') && ($.trim(value) !== 'EA')) {
         return 'Only numbers allowed or EA';
     }
}
```